# Can Wrappers in Orchard CMS have alternates?

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, shapes

I'm curious if I can somehow make the Widget.Wrapper shape (or other wrappers) alternateable, because it contains most of the widgets' HTML code. I don't like rich IF statements in cshtml files, therefore I'd rather use a clear solution using the alternates mechanism - being able to create alternates like these:

```
Widget.Wrapper-[ZoneName].cshtml
Widget.Wrapper-[WidgetId].cshtml
Widget.Wrapper-url-[UrlAlternate].cshtml
```

etc.

Is that possible? Or are the wrappers a special case - and in that case why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
You can do it with IShapeTableProvider.
Catch the shape that your widget it rendering, decide which wrapper you want, and then add a new wrapper.

```
builder.Describe("YourShapeHere")
    .OnDisplaying(displaying=>{
        displaying.ShapeMetadata.Wrappers.Add("Widget_Wrapper-" + displaying.Shape.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not exactly an alternate (cause no, there are no alternates for wrappers), it just adds a new wrapper, it doesn not remove the existing one.